# Como puedo simular una consulta asíncrona en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos estoy tratando de realizar una consulta asíncrona en MySQL, el código de mi consulta actualmente es el siguiente.

```
    select r.tipo, @id_uni := uni.ubicacion_id as id_uni, 
    (select t2.id  from ((select * from (select t.id, t.nombre, @pv := t.ubicacionpadre 
    ubicacionpadre,t.tipoUbicacion_id
    from (select * from ubicacion order by id desc) as t
    join (select @pv := @id_uni) as tmp
    where t.id = @pv) tmp2 where tmp2.tipoUbicacion_id = 1)) as t2) as idpais
    from req_compras r
    join unidad_empresa uni on r.id_unidad = uni.id
    where r.id = 2867;
```

`join (select @pv := @id_uni)` el `@id_uni` es quien espera el resultado de la consulta de más arriba.

Comment: Que seria una consulta asincronica?

Comment: Sé que eso no existe acá, solo use el término para ilustrar lo que se necesita, algo parecido a la asincronía en JavaScript, algo como poner un setTimeOut de JavaScript, en pocas palabras seria que el resultado, él, id que les mencione, espera el resultado de la consulta inmediatamente anterior a ella.

Comment: O sea.. algo asi como una subconsulta queres vos... donde primero se haga una consulta, y en base a eso se haga otra?  Igual el concepto que estas describiendo es raro.. las consultas son algebra de conjuntos.. Se arma de a un conjunto por ves... con lo cual, no se que sentido tiene tu consulta... tu join no joinea nada... tal vez lo que queres hacer sea mucho mas simple???